# Java: Date conversion output error

Tags: java, arrays

Having issues on this program getting the output correct. I've included parameters that help decipher what is a valid date input (i.e. 3/22/2014) vs. an invalid input (i.e. 3/57/2014). These are located within my for loop in the if statement. However, when I run the program, I keep receiving the else statement's output and I'm not sure why. I've switched array types from String and int with no luck. Do you see my error? Thanks

```
  import java.util.Scanner;
  import javax.swing.*;
public class ConvertDate
    {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
     String enteredDate, month, day, year;
     final String[] monthID = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July",      
        "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};

     final int[] monthIDArray = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};
     final String[] monthValidSingleInputs = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10",  
        "11", "12"};
     final String[] monthValidDosInputs = {"01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", 
        "10", "11", "12"};
     final String[] monthsDays = {"31", "28", "31", "30", "31", "30", "31", "31", "30", "31", 
        "30", "31"};
     final int[] intDaysArray = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};

     final int JANUARY = 1;
     final int DECEMBER = 12;
     int selectedDate;
     int x;

     enteredDate = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a date in the format MM/DD/YYYY");
```

Using indexOf in order to distinguish inputs inside of /

```
     int slashIndex = enteredDate.indexOf("/");
  //Finding the month
        month = enteredDate.substring(0, slashIndex);
           int intMonth = Integer.parseInt(month);
        enteredDate = enteredDate.substring(slashIndex + 1);
        enteredDate = enteredDate.trim();
  //Finding the day
        slashIndex = enteredDate.indexOf("/");
        day = enteredDate.substring(0, slashIndex);
           int intDay = Integer.parseInt(day);
        enteredDate = enteredDate.trim();
        enteredDate = enteredDate.substring(slashIndex + 1);
  //Finding the year
        year = enteredDate.substring(0, 4);
           int intYear = Integer.parseInt(year);
        enteredDate = enteredDate.trim();
```

Output statements

```
  for(x = 0; x < monthID.length; ++x)
{
if(((month == monthValidSingleInputs[x]) || (month == monthValidDosInputs[x])) && (intDay <= 
       intDaysArray[x]) && ((intMonth >= JANUARY) && (intMonth <= DECEMBER)))
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Date is: " + monthID[x] 
           + " " + intDay + ", " + year);
           else
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please re-run program, entries not valid.");
              break;
     }}}
```

Comment: Use String.equals instead of == to compare string values.

Comment: The errors are with the `==` as well as with the `break` statement which terminates the loop after its first iteration. I have posted the corrected code as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary issue was with your `for loop`. Since you had been using the `break` statement inside the `for loop`, it was getting terminated after your first iteration.

And another issue with your code was that, you were using `==` to compare strings. You can't compare two strings using `==` operator. You should use the method `equals()` or `equalsIgnoreCase()` to compare two strings.

You have to change the block indicated as ***'output statements'*** in order to get the correct output. The modified code is shown below:

```
    boolean flag=false;
```

`for(x = 0; x < monthID.length; ++x)
    {
      if(((month.equals(monthValidSingleInputs[x])) || (month.equals(monthValidDosInputs[x]))) && 
          (intDay <= intDaysArray[x]) && ((intMonth >= JANUARY) && (intMonth <= DECEMBER)))
      {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Date is: " + monthID[x] + " " + intDay + ", " + year);
           flag=true;
           break;
      }
     }

     if(flag==false)
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please re-run program, entries not valid.");
  }
}`

Comment: Thank you, Praveen Vinny. This solution solves a few of my other problems with other programs as well!